# vim: ft=c: in initial comment does not trigger C-Mode

Tags: c, vim, editor

Using the sequence "vim: command ...:" inside the first line of a file usually triggers vim to execute the given command. However, my files contain

/* vim: set ft=c: */

and VIM is not setup in C-mode. How could I fix this?

Comment: Did you check 'modeline' and 'modelines' options?

Comment: For what it's worth, it works for me under Windows 7.

Comment: What does `:set modeline` say? If it says `nomodeline` then mode-line processing is turned off (If it says `modeline` it is turned on). Some systems turn it off by default for security reasons, but you can turn it on in your `.vimrc` (or `_vimrc` in Windows) file.

Comment: @IanAbbott: You mean `:set modeline?` (with a question mark - `:set modeline` without the question mark will *set* it, so it's no good for diagnostics)

Comment: "modelines" and "modeline" are two separate variables. I had "set modelines=1" being set and was not aware that "set modeline" is required additionally. Thanks.